# iteration with replacing strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files: one is a list of terms, and the other is a text file. I want to print the text file without the terms present in the first file.

I tried this:

```
import codecs  
import ast
list_file = codecs.open(list_file).read()
text_file = codecs.open(text_file).read()
import ast
li = ast.literal_eval(list_file)
for l in li:
    print(text_file.replace((l, ""))
```

The problem here is the iteration. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are overkill in my opinion:

```
for l in li:
    text_file = text_file.replace(l, '')
```

Remember that in python strings are *immutable* meaning they can't be edited in-place. That means each time you replace, you are making a copy of the string with the replacement performed, and re-assigning the `text_file` string with this value.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you're iterating over the list of replacements, rather than the lines of text file.

I would use the [RE module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to do the replacement, something like this:

```
subre = re.compile("|".join(li))
```

I guess it should be:

```
for tl in text_file:
  print re.sub(subre, "", tl)
```